# Can I backup iTunes 9 before upgrading to iTunes 10?

Tags: itunes, backup, upgrade

I am happy with iTunes 9 and am a bit leery of upgrading to iTunes 10 on my Mac based on some feedback I've heard from others. Can I duplicate `iTunes.app` in my Applications folder prior to running Software Update to update to iTunes 10, and use the backup iTunes to run iTunes 9 if I am not happy with iTunes 10? I know this works with some applications like Final Cut Pro but not with others like Safari.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't see why not.  If you're paranoid, you may also want to backup the iTunes prefs (`~/Library/com.apple.itunes*`), and/or any config files you find in your iTunes music folder (`~/Music/iTunes/` in my case).

Answer (score 0):

I just did this and I can confirm that it did work. However as Harv said, if you do this make a backup of the old files, specifically your library, as iTunes 10 will upgrade your "iTunes Library" file and iTunes 9 will refuse to read it.